# 2D Array from HTML

Tags: html, arrays, csv, powershell, powershell-2.0

My task is to convert an HTML table to a 2D array so that I can write the contents to a CSV file. I'm getting hung up on the best way to create the second array dimension. Here's what I have so far (with sample data):

```
$data = '<table style="width:100%"> <tr> <td>Jill</td> <td>Smith</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Eve</td> <td>Jackson</td> <td>94</td> </tr> </table> '
$data = [regex]::matches($data, '<table.*?>(.+)</table>')
$data = $data[0].Groups[1].value
$arr = @()
$arr = [regex]::matches($data, '<tr.*?>(.*?)</tr>') | % {$_.Groups[1].value}
```

I now have an array of `<tr>` lines (minus the `<tr>` tags). Is there a way to next split out the `<td>` elements and create an array of arrays from these? I could probably brute force my way through this, but I feel like there's a cleaner and probably more optimal way.

By the way, I'm using v2 of PowerShell.

Comment: This seems to be the missing magic line. If anyone sees any glaring errors here, I'd be happy to hear them!
`0..($arr.Length-1) | % { $arr[$_] = [regex]::matches($arr[$_], '<td.*?>(.*?)</td>') | % {$_.Groups[1].value}  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a closer look at what you have so far you'll notice a pattern: you take a string with an HTML fragment, match it against a regular expression `<tag.*?>(.*?)</tag>`, and extract the captured group (the part between parentheses) from the match. You do that for the `<table>` tag as well as for the `<tr>` tags. Use the same approach to extract the content of the `<td>` tag for each row.

```
$arr | ForEach-Object {
  [regex]::matches($_, '<td.*?>(.*?)</td>') | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
  }
}
```

The `[regex]::matches() | ForEach-Object {}` statement gives you a list/array of the `<td>` values for each row. If you append these lists to an empty array by prepending them with the unary comma operator, like so

```
$td = @()
$arr | ForEach-Object {
  $td += ,@([regex]::matches($_, '<td.*?>(.*?)</td>') | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
  })
}
```

you append the array as a whole instead of appending each individual element, giving you a result like this:

```
[ [ 'Jill', 'Smith', 50 ], [ 'Eve', 'Jackson', 94 ] ]
```

instead of a flat array:

```
[ 'Jill', 'Smith', 50, 'Eve', 'Jackson', 94 ]
```

The result isn't exactly a 2-dimensional array (it's actually an array of arrays whereas a 2-dimensional array would be a single array with, well, 2 dimensions). It's how you'd usually handle this kind of thing in PowerShell, though.

To get a better understanding of what exactly you're doing here you may want to read up on [operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx), [arrays](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx), and [regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).